# Oracle select data by contiguous date blocks

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an Oracle database and I have a table that has 2 columns with data like so:

```
HASH | DATE
-----------------
abcd | 2017-11-01
abcd | 2017-11-02
abcd | 2017-11-03
wxyz | 2017-11-04
wxyz | 2017-11-05
abcd | 2017-11-06
wxyz | 2017-11-07
abcd | 2017-11-08
abcd | 2017-11-09
lmno | 2017-11-10
lmno | 2017-11-11
```

I want to know the windows of time that each hash is seen. So like

```
hash | start      | end
------------------------------
abcd | 2017-11-01 | 2017-11-03
wxyz | 2017-11-04 | 2017-11-05
abcd | 2017-11-06 | 2017-11-06
wxyz | 2017-11-07 | 2017-11-07
abcd | 2017-11-08 | 2017-11-09
lmno | 2017-11-10 | 2017-11-11
```

What I have so far is basically this:

```
SELECT HASH, MIN(DATE) ST, MAX(DATE) ED
FROM HASH_TABLE 
GROUP BY HASH 
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

And this almost works but it will give me like "abcd" as a start of 2017-11-01 and an end of 2017-11-09 which "hides" the fact that it switched in the middle.

Is there some way to group these results by contiguous date/time "blocks"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like "gaps and islands" problem:

```
WITH cte("hash","date") AS (
    SELECT 'abcd',  DATE'2017-11-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abcd',  DATE'2017-11-02' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abcd',  DATE'2017-11-03' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wxyz',  DATE'2017-11-04' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wxyz',  DATE'2017-11-05' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abcd',  DATE'2017-11-06' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wxyz',  DATE'2017-11-07' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abcd',  DATE'2017-11-08' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abcd',  DATE'2017-11-09' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'lmno',  DATE'2017-11-10' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'lmno',  DATE'2017-11-11' FROM dual 
)
select "hash"
      ,min("date") as startdate
      ,max("date") as enddate
from (
    select "date","hash"
         , row_number() over (order by "date") 
         - row_number() over (partition by "hash" order by "date") as grp
    from cte
) A
group by "hash", grp
ORDER BY startdate;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=938074e12545424109690143b039dd26)**

Comment: This looks like it's basically right. You need to wrap the whole thing in a select * from (...) order by startdate to correctly order the results but otherwise, it appears to work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without  `row_number` and `partition by`? The software tool I'm using doesn't support all of these advanced keywords.

Answer (score 0):

> **desc hash_table**
>
> `hash   varchar2(4)`
>    `date_  date`

```
select hash, min(date_) start_, max(date_) end_
  from
    (
     select h.hash, h.date_, row_number() over (partition by hash order by date_) rn
       from hash_table h 
    )
  group by hash, date_ - rn
  order by 2;
```

Comment: This loses all of the "abcd" in the middle.

Comment: @MichaelB yes, you're right. So, i've edited my answer.

Comment: Cool, but now it seems to select all of the records instead of the groups

Comment: @MichaelB this is the most summarized method i could reach :)